# Finite morphisms between algebraic varieties are closed is a local property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

A finite morphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ between varieties (variety can be covered by a finite number of affine varieties) by definition is one where we can choose an open cover $U_i$ of $Y$ consisting of affines so that their inverse images are also affine and $k[f^{-1}U_i]$ is a finite $k[U_i]$ module through the induced map.

Now, in order to prove that the image is a closed set, author says it is a local property on $Y$, but I don't get how $im(f) \cap U_i$ being closed in $U_i$ subspace topology proves that $im(f)$ is closed in $Y$.

I am using Kempf's algebraic varieties.

Comment: Hint: what's the complement of the image of $f$, both inside $Y$ and inside each $U_i$?

Comment: What do you want to show exactly ? $\Bbb{C}^*$ is not closed in $\Bbb{C}$ and it is the image of $f:V(xy-1)\to \Bbb{C},f(x,y)=x$. For each $y\in f(X)$ there is some affine open $U\subset Y,U\ni y$ such that $f(X)\cap U$ is closed in $U$. This has to do with your finite $k[U_i]$-module assumption.

Comment: @KReiser thanks, that works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer here.
$Y-f(X) = Y \cap f(X)^c = \cup_i (U_i \cap f(X)^c)$

is open since if each of $U_i \cap f(X)^c$ is open.